# Correcting error messages emitted by ListPlot

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, homework

I have an assignment to use `Module` and in which I have to implement:

1. The input of the program are a list of numbers and a list of strings
2. Check whether every number in the first list are integer or not
3. Check whether every string in the second list are truly strings or not
4. Find the maximum and the mean of the first list (the numbers list)
5. Plot the data and the mean:

[image: the picture above is how the plot output supposed to look like]

That's how the plot supposed to look like. Unfortunately, mine look like this:

[image]

So, what do you think is wrong?

Comment: `string = If[All[...],...]` should be `string = If[AllTrue[...],...]`. In future, please post code (using the backticks) rather than screenshots - it's easier for us to copy it than type out code from a picture.

Comment: Also your input `{i, am,so,confused}` is a list of symbols but you want strings so it should be `{"i","am","so","confused"}`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**: The source of the error is the second `ListLinePlot`. You can see this because if you click on the orange bubble {...} on the error and select `Show Stack Trace` you get this:

```
> Message[ListLinePlot::lpn, 3.6]

> ListLinePlot[18/5, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]
```

You are trying to plot a single number 18/5, the mean. You need to provide at least two points to get a line in `ListLinePlot`. To fix this use `ListLinePlot[{{0,mean},{Length[ang],mean}}]`.

**Problem 2**: You need to use `AllTrue` instead of `All` when checking the list of strings.

Also you can shorten your `If` statements. If they fail and the `Print`'s are triggered, then `integer` and `string` get assigned the return value of `Print` which is `Null`. I assume you really want `False`.

**Problem 3**: You want to pass in strings into your function `{"i", "am", "so", "confused"}`, not the list of symbols `{i,am,so,confused}`

Putting it all together:

```
fungsi[ang_, str_] := Module[{integer, string, max, mean, gambar},
  integer = AllTrue[ang, IntegerQ];
  string = AllTrue[str, StringQ];
  If[Not[integer], Print["not integers"]];
  If[Not[string], Print["not strings"]];
  max = Max[ang];
  mean = Mean[ang];
  gambar = 
   Show[
    ListLinePlot[ang, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
    ListLinePlot[{{0,mean},{Length[ang],mean}}, PlotStyle -> {Green,Dashed}],
    ListLinePlot[{{0,max}, {Length[ang],max}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
   ]
 ]
fungsi[{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {"i", "am", "so", "confused"}]
```

You can also add lines and other graphics to plots using `Epilog` like this:

```
ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {Purple, Dashed, Line[{{0, 2}, {4, 2}}]}]
```